# Определить ключ в ссылке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Задача такая:
есть форма поиска (поиск обычный, без ajax), и после перезагрузки страницы необходимо пользователя отправить к нужному блоку (скролл до определённого места страницы, а именно к форме поиска, прокрутив ниже, оставив позади шапку с меню).

Второй вариант: найти определённый ключ в ссылке и если он есть выполнить скролл до блока с нужным id.

Ссылка имеет вид _https://domen/razdel/?query=search_key
Собственно зоной интереса является ?query, т.к. всё остальное может меняться.
Нашёл свойства window.location.search, это при помощи него надо реализовывать? бы бы благодарен правильному решению.

Если описать функцию целиком, то так:
если страница меньше 1000 px в ширину (определить при загрузке) -> если в ссылке содержится ?query -> выполнить скролл до объекта с id="main" с отступом сверху от него на 50px.

И главное, чтобы это можно было реализовать на чистом js, т.к. jquery я подключаю в конце страницы.

Answer (score -1):

К сожалению в сниппете не работает, видимо скрипт снипета выполняется в SandBox,  на реальном файле, работает.

Когда будете тестировать на реальном файле, просто добавьте после открытия в конец например `?query=2`, на файл это не повлияет, но позволит скрипту сработать.

Почему сделан `setTimeout` смотрим в уточняющих комментариях.

```js
function tryScroll() {
  if (window.location.search.indexOf("?query") >= 0 && document.body.clientWidth < 1000) {
    var el = document.getElementById("main");
    window.scroll(0, findScrollPosition(el) + 50);
  }
}

function findScrollPosition(obj) {
  var curtop = 0;
  if (obj.offsetParent) {
    do {
      curtop += obj.offsetTop;
    } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
    return curtop;
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  window.setTimeout(tryScroll, 0);
};
```

```css
.start {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 500px;
}

#main {
  background-color: green;
}

.end {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="start">
  start
</div>

<div id="main">
  main
</div>

<div class="end">
  end
</div>
```

Comment: да я так и понял, и сразу создал файл для пробы. использовал ваш последний вариант.
есть два важный момента:
1. вы основываетесь просто на наличии get в ссылке, а надо работать именно с ?query, т.к. на живом сайте есть и другие запросы, например ?page= - на них скрипт не должен реагировать.

2. с одним гет запросом отрабатывает только 1 раз, дальше можно обновлять или делать что угодно, скроссить не будет.

Comment: @Aaron с query добавил, теперь проверяется. А по тому что должен один раз сработать не понял, скрипт один раз работает после загрузки страницы, повторно он может сработать только при повторной загрузке

Comment: @Aaron Понял ваш вопрос по пункту 2, но тут всё впорядке, он обрабатывается один раз, как видим вызов прямой, никаких обработчиков не стоит.

Comment: да, увидел)
я понимаю, о том и говорю, если загрузить страницу с ?query=qwe, то скролл будет, если страницу обновить или в строке браузера ещё раз "ввод" выполнить, то уже не скроллит, до тех пор, пока сам гет запрос не изменится (т.е. qwe а что-то другое).

Comment: как-то этот момент можно реализовать?, предположим человек не изменит поисковую фразу, но снова отправит запрос. страница перезагрузится, но при нынешнем варианте уже не будет скроллить к нужному блоку.

Comment: если обновить страницу, то запрос повторяется, если ввести новые данные в строку запроса и нажать энтер то запрос снова повторится, а на повторный запрос скрипт снова сработает. И тут сделать ничего нельзя, так как страница не помнит состояния которые было в прошлом запросе.

Comment: понял вопрос, сейчас посмотрим как можно решить, так работает потому что браузер запоминает текущий скролл

Comment: поправьте, если не прав, если бы он запоминал, то возвращал меня на место, а я целенаправленно поднимаю страницу вверх и обновляю, в результате остаюсь там же, а не опускаюсь.

Comment: да, но я нашёл решение, в ответе уже обновил, хотя не могу сказать что оно супер красивое, но работает

Comment: setTimeout? вы что обнуляете и запускаете по новой?

Comment: @Aaron дело в том что если его не делать, то браузер востанавливает запомненное положение скролла, а с помощью setTimeout мы его обманываем )). Если вам ответ подходит, отметьте его пожалуйста.

Comment: @Aaron setTimeout это запуск функции по таймеру, в данном случае через 0 секунд. Этим мы выводим функциию из синхронного стандартного потока исполнения метода onload, после чего функция обработчика onload успешно завершается, после отрабатывает браузерный скролл, а наша функция запускается асинхронно уже после.